# How do I fix the permissions on /system/app on my Kindle fire

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, file-permissions

I attempted to root my Amazon Kindle.  That seemed to go well, but when I tried to add the Google App Market, I apparently made a big booboo, because now I am in "constant reboot, 'kindle fire' screen of death". That is, the fire won't boot, and it just stares at me with "kindle fire".

I've googled around, and found people with my exact problem, but no way to fix it.  And my problem is this:

The permissions on my /system/app folder are as follows?

```
d--------- root     root              2012-01-28 13:26 app
```

Yeah, I know, not good.

So, how can I fix it?  I've tried the various methods out there, but basically, because the directory is so hosed on permissions, I can't do anything.  For instance, I can't run

```
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock2 /system
```

because I get

```
mount: Operation not permitted
```

and when I try

```
adb root
```

I get the cryptic

```
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

So I am dead in the water.

Can anyone help me fix my permissions on /system/app?

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery and/or bootloader installed? If not then you may be stuck unless you can make yourself a "factory cable" (or find one made by someone else).

Comment: Agreed with eldarerathis.  The cable may also be called a "jig".

Comment: Actually, another important factor is what firmware version you have. If you have 6.2.1 or lower you may be able to use `adb` to get into fastboot.

Comment: Wow -- thanks for the tip about "Factory Cables".  Interesting stuff.

Comment: I have 6.2.2 as my firmware.

Comment: If you want you could try [this method for getting into fastboot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1414832). It's only tested against 6.2.1, but I suppose it's possible it could work on 6.2.2 (though I have no idea). Otherwise I think you'll need to use a factory cable or the "[shorting trick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1405052)", which requires physically opening the Kindle Fire (and Linux).

Comment: Amazon is graciously sending me a new one, and I'm sure when I return mine they will be using a factory cable to reset it.  But I have 30 days to return it, so I may take the time to try to build a factory cable myself just for the experience.

Comment: Let us know how the factory cable goes.